# Unable to connect specific monitor via DP 1.2 to laptop

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, drivers, external-display

I have an DELL U2414H which I'm trying to connect to an Alienware 17 R4 via the DP 1.2.

Whenever I connect the monitor to the laptop:

- The laptop freezes for 5-10 seconds then it's ok, then it freezes again, and it keeps doing this
- Takes about 1-2 minutes and then the laptop sees the secondary display for a couple of seconds and then it doesn't see it at all.

Other notes:

- If I connect the monitor through HDMI it works
- I have 2 monitors the same happens no matter which one of the two I use.
- If I connect the screen to another Alienware R4 17 (practically identical, they probably have consecutive serial number) I don't have any problems.
- The screens work perfectly if I connect them to another Asus ROG laptop
- If I connect the laptop to another brand of monitors via Display Port it works.

Considering the behavior I'd say it a driver problem but I have no idea how to fix it except a format or a factory reset which is something I can **not** do.

What I've tried

- Restart
- Uninstall drivers for both graphics cards
- Uninstall the drivers for the monitor
- Completely delete the driver for the graphics cards(where possible)
- Upgrade drivers to the latest version

I have:

- Windows 10 Pro 1709 Build 16299.492
- GTX 1060 with 6GB
- Intel Graphics HD 630

Maybe of importance, when I first tried to connect the monitor it was daisy chained to the second one.

And in case someone wants to know why I'm not just using HDMI, the answer is because I want to daisy chain them.

Comment: not all DP connections are truly hot-swappable, even though the protocol should be. Test from a cold boot.

Comment: @Tetsujin Are you suggesting I boot with the monitor connected? Also on the laptop connecting I was able to just plug while it was running. Will give it a try thanks

Comment: Did you try running the Dell command update utility?

Comment: @MassimilianoLoi As far as I can see it doesn't support Alienware and I've downloaded the latest drivers from the Dell site so I'm not sure what that supposed to help me with exactly, but I'll give it a shot